SQL Inner Join and Total Participation
I came across this multiple-choice question in a past-year paper. Why is the second option wrong?

Doesn't total participation mean that all rows in that particular table are in a relationship with the other table? Which would give us 20 rows since there are 20 rows in enrolled?

As I see it, all answers are wrong. The query could return any number of rows between 0 and 120 rows, depending on the presence or absence of data integrity. Are there any constraints in the database model?

@TheImpaler that said 1:N relationship on answer C, so it makes sense to have 6-20 rows.

@Jeff Beh, question needs best answer, so it choose answer C. answer B can be right, but not best answer

Actually, I believe answer B is incorrect as per @TheImpaler's answer. As answer B doesn't specify anything about repeat values in student, only that each record in enrolment has at least one record in student, it could be that all stu_id's are the same (making 120 rows). In contrast, answer C makes it clear that it's not a many-to-many (or 1 enrolment to many students) meaning each stu_id used in enrolment is unique in student.
